# Issue with pagination in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to the angularjs. I try to develop the page with the pagination option using angularjs. Every thing goes well until yesterday, but suddenly the pagination option not working properly. If i am selecting the second page means, it will send the page number '2' to the backup end process the data and again the function called with the page number '1'. So, the second page data getting overwritted with the first page data.

Here i have posted the sample data

Html Part :

```
<tbody style="color:#000;" ng-hide="mergereport == null || mergereport == ''" dir-paginate="itr in mergereport | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | itemsPerPage:10 track by $index" pagination-id="paginateID1" total-items="totCount">
    <!-- Some <tr> placed below -->
</tbody>

<div ng-if ="mergereport != null && mergereport != '' ">
    <dir-pagination-controls
        max-size="10"
        direction-links="true"
        pagination-id="paginateID1"
        boundary-links="true" 
        on-page-change="GetSelPageReport(pageno)" style="float:right;">
    </dir-pagination-controls> 
</div>
```

Controller.Js

```
$scope.GetSelPageReport = function(pageno) {

    if (pageno != 0) {
        alert(" The page Number Received :::: " + pageno);
    }
}
```

Here the function "GetSelPageReport()" calling twice, first the actual selected value(for example, if i am seleting 3 means with the value of 3), next time its called the with the pageno 1.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What is `on-page-change`?

Comment: Looks like `on-page-change` is getting triggered twice

Comment: Please share a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/)

Comment: Did you check this example http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview

Comment: Hi Bik

Thanks for your reply. I just replace the existing dirPagination.js file with  the file which is available in the given link, after changing the file its work for me. Thanks for your Help.